# How can I redirect some (but not all) http requests on one IIS host to https on another IIS host?

Tags: iis, rewrite

We have the following requirements:

- redirect **http**://**host1**.example.com/**resource1**/* to **https**://**host2**.example.com/**resource1**/* (retaining everything including /resource1/* and query strings, etc.)
- do NOT redirect http://**host1**.example.com/**resource2**/* at all
- we cannot use Application Request Routing
- IIS 7.5

We can use either redirect or rewrite, whichever works. It seems like setting up an inbound rewrite rule with the 'reverse proxy' option (which creates a condition using an Input with {CACHE_URL}) comes close, but I cannot get it to work with a Pattern in the 'Match URL' section of /resource1/*.  Redirect seems to enable redirecting a resource to another resource on the same host only, not on a different host.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: [URL Rewrite 2.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in several ways using [IIS Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

1. you can create redirects only for handful of the links you need
2. You can use regex/pattern matching to redirect a similar set of links

Here is a visual guide on how to use [IIS Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)